# How to use the same titleformat for numbered and unnumbered chapters/sections?

Tags: titlesec

I'm using titlesec with explicit option, and I have a titleformat for chapters like this:

```latex
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
{\huge\bfseries} 
{\thechapter. #1 } 
{0pt}
{}    
\titlespacing{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

I need to put some "\chapter*{name}" in my document, and I have seen that they doesn't appear until I put the next code:

```latex
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\huge\bfseries} 
{#1 } 
{0pt}
{}    
\titlespacing{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

Is there any way to not repeat the code (I know it's not 100% equal) and use one maybe the unnumbered to use for numbered chapter?

Thanks!